# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') - Error retuned by Chainlink Functions oracle

Tags: chainlink

I have been building with Chainlink Functions for Chainlink Spring 2023 hacakthon.

I cloned the functions hardhat starter kit template from Chainlink and now this is working repository [here](https://github.com/gabrielantonyxaviour/chainlink-spring-contracts)
All the logic and execution seems to work perfectly in the Local Sandbox Simulation.
The issue occurs when I try to execute it in polygon mumbai. Deployed contract [here](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x7de445626bdc3dadc2953d08ff5765fb038bb558#code).
If you check the latest Event log `ErrorOccured`, I get the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` returned from the oracle.
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRTCU.png)

This is my cloud function

```
if (!secrets.accessToken) {
  throw Error("Need to set ACCESS_TOKEN environment variable")
}
console.log(secrets.accessToken)
const emailRequest = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${secrets.accessToken}`,
  },
})

const [emailResponse] = await Promise.all([emailRequest])
console.log(emailResponse)
if (!emailResponse.error) {
  const result = emailResponse.data.email
  return Functions.encodeString(result)
} else {
  throw Error("Error getting email")
}
```

I highly doubt that there is something wrong with the way I send my secrets to the contract

Here is how I got my encrypted secrets URL:

1. I got the secretsURL from the secrets by the gist created by the `buildRequestJSON.js` function in the template.
2. I copied the data from the hosted gist and deployed it myself using nft.storage
3. I passed the secrets URL in the `request.js` in the variable `simulatedSecretsURLBytes`(line 86).
4. Then I ran `npx hardhat functions-request --contract 0x7De445626bdc3dadC2953D08Ff5765fB038bb558 --subid 1752 --configpath ./Functions-request-config.js --network polygonMumbai` in the terminal.

It returned me this error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` in the hex format in the terminal.

Please provide any assistance possible

Comment: Can you also share your config file?  Sometimes empty strings in args or secrets values can produce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with this line:

```
const [emailResponse] = await Promise.all([emailRequest])
```

Can you try to restructure the code like this?

```
if (!secrets.accessToken) {
  throw Error("Need to set ACCESS_TOKEN environment variable")
}
console.log(secrets.accessToken)
const emailResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me",
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${secrets.accessToken}`,
  },
})

console.log(emailResponse)
if (!emailResponse.error) {
  const result = emailResponse.data.email
  return Functions.encodeString(result)
} else {
  throw Error("Error getting email")
}
```

You can also try returning an encoded string to see if the `emailResponse` is in the correct format.

Comment: I don't this this will completely fix the problem, but should help with the debugging process.